# Как можно отправлять координаты каждые 5 секунд?

Tags: java, android

Вопрос такой, как можно сделать что-бы на сервер отправлялись мои координаты раз в 5 секунд

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int PERMISSION_ID = 44;
FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
TextView latTextView, lonTextView;
private Socket socket;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ConnectionAsyncTask con = new ConnectionAsyncTask();
    con.execute("192.168.0.40", "7788");

    latTextView = findViewById(R.id.latTextView);
    lonTextView = findViewById(R.id.lonTextView);
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    getLastLocation();
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private void getLastLocation() {
    if (checkPermissions()) {
        if (isLocationEnabled()) {
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(
                    new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                            Location location = task.getResult();
                            if (location == null) {
                                requestNewLocationData();
                            } else {
                                Gson gson = new Gson();
                                String jsonCoords;

                                //Этот фрагмент кода


                                        double lat = location.getLatitude();
                                        double lon = location.getLongitude();

                                        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(lat));
                                        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(lon));

                                        Model model = new Model(lat, lon);
                                        jsonCoords = gson.toJson(model);

                                        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(model));

                                        SendAsyncTask sendAsyncTask = new SendAsyncTask();// {"lat": 37.4334, "lon": -122.32}
                                        sendAsyncTask.execute(jsonCoords);

                                             //

                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Turn on location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } else {
        requestPermissions();
    }
}


@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private void requestNewLocationData() {

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(0);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(0);
    mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(1);

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback,
            Looper.myLooper()
    );

}

private LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        Location mLastLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
        latTextView.setText(mLastLocation.getLatitude() + "");
        lonTextView.setText(mLastLocation.getLongitude() + "");
    }
};

private boolean checkPermissions() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void requestPermissions() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            PERMISSION_ID
    );
}

private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
    );
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_ID) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            getLastLocation();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (checkPermissions()) {
        getLastLocation();
    }

}

class ConnectionAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Socket> {
    Socket s = null;

    @Override
    protected Socket doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            s = new Socket(params[0], Integer.parseInt(params[1]));
            socket = s;
            Log.d("Tag", s.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return s;
    }

}

class SendAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try (PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()))) {
            printWriter.write(params[0] + "\n");
            printWriter.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Оно? https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer

Comment: Можно по разному. Например через `Timer` или c `rxJava`. И лучше всего это в сервисе делать. Однако тут зависит от условий задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте таймер, а ещё лучше сервис с таймером и периодически отправляйте. В любом случае координаты у Вас обновятся не раньше, чем "железный" датчик устройства обнаружит изменение его местоположения и уведомит об этом систему.

Немножко уточню ответ, потому что из-за этого могут возникнуть дальнейшие сложности. Если нужно отсылать данные только тогда, когда приложение открыто создавать отдельный компонент Service для этого не стоит. Достаточно создать отдельный объект, который будет отвечать за отправку данных, внутри которого будет лежать таймер, и который будет крутиться на отдельном потоке. Так приложение будет потреблять меньше ресурсов. Если же данные должны отправляться в фоновом режиме, то обычный Service не поможет, необходимо использовать ForegroundService.